# Regular expression to verify a username

Tags: regex

I have to verify a username, the requirements are as follows:

- length is at least 8 with a maximum of 20
- it **has to** contain letters (a-z), no capital letters
- it **can** contain the symbols dot(.), hyphen(-) or underscore(_), other symbols are forbidden

Does someone know the regular expression for this?

Comment: nice question. what is the effort? have searched this in SO?

Comment: See online documentation [regular-expressions.info/](http://www.regular-expressions.info/)

Answer (score 3):

Since you didn't show much effort in trying to figure this out neither will I. However, to give you a headstart I will provide you with a regex that will kind of help you with building your desired regex:

`[a-z\.\-\_]{8,20}`

In here you can see:
`[ ]` - a character class: any characters inside it can be matched
`{ }` - quantifier: between 8 and 20 characters long
`a-z` - range all characters from `a` to `z`
`\.` - match a literal dot
`\-` - match a literal hyphen
`_` - match a literal underscore

However, this regex is buggy: for example, a username consisting of 8 (or more) dots is also accepted: `.........`, so are the combinations of only symbols, without letters: `-_-__-_._-`. I believe this is not an expected behaviour.

You can see a demo here: [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/eX1vU7/2)

Comment: Hint: Lookahead expressions (starting with `(?=`). With this you can fix the bugs mentioned by Asunez.